# JavaScript ui-autocomplete не реагируется на focus()

Tags: javascript, input, jquery-ui, javascript-events, focus

У меня есть проблема с использованием `focus()` (чтобы поставить фокус в поле поиска после нажатия на кнопку) на элементе, который имеет  `ui-autocomplete`.

```
<input id="headerSearch" class="header-search-form-input form-control ui-autocomplete-input" name="query" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

и когда я использую `$('#headerSearch').focus()` чтобы поместить курсор в это поле - это не срабатывает.
Я нашел что это может быть потому что поле уже имеет это событие. Я проверил это через Google Chrome EventListener и да, это поле имеет `event.focus()`.
И я теперь не понимаю как я могу поместить курсор после действия в это поле, если оно уже занято этим событием?

Спасибо за помощь.

**UPD**
Я нашел как удалить событие, но это все равно не сработало. Фокус в поле не ставится, чтобы сразу можно было писать.
Хотя когда делаю это в Консоли - все ок.

```
$('#headerSearch').off('focus'); 
$('#headerSearch').focus();
```

Comment: `чтобы поместить курсор в это поле` - не совсем понимаю... Вы хотите поместить курсор (который указатель) пользователя в какое-то поле? Если это так, то же невозможно, JavaScript не имеет доступа к движению курсора. А так фокус вроде должен появиться, если не появляется, то тогда проверьте элемент на наличие других событий фокуса, т.к. события могут предотвратить фокус.

Comment: Поместить фокус в поле, чтобы пользователь сразу печатать в этом поле мог. Базовая вещь, встречающаяся везде. Конкретно мой вопрос по focus() в поле которое уже занято событием.

Comment: Не все элементы могут иметь фокус

Comment: `input` может иметь фокус

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При нажатии на кнопку появлялся слой в котором был `input`, видимо (я предполагаю), что сам `input` не успевал "появиться" для браузера и он не мог получить фокус там, я сделал так (не знаю костыль это или нет, но сработало).

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#headerSearch').focus(); }, 100);
```

Дальше поэксперементировав я увидел, что не обязательно удалять событие `focus` у элемента `$('#headerSearch').off('focus');`, но мне непонятно почему? Если кто-то знает ответ - буду благодарен.

Предполагаю, что это не событие, а метод, поэтому смысл удалять событие, если я его не занимаю.

*Меня ввело в заблуждение то, что везде пишут в ответах, что если не ставится фокус в поле - посмотрите не занято ли событие и удалите его тогда.*